# Setting innerHTML between empty string and full string in WebKit on floated elements causes overflow

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I'm seeing this issue where if I toggle the innerHTML of either a floated element or an element nested inside one, it floats outside the container once I toggle back from an empty string to any text or markup.  Oddly, in the example below, if I remove text-transform from the inline CSS, the problem goes away.

This is happening in Chrome 9.0.597.19 and Safari 5.0.3 (WebKit build 6533.19.4) in OS X 10.6.5.

Any ideas whether this is a WebKit bug or something else?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Safari Float Bug</title>

 <style type="text/css">
        .titlebar {
            background: #eee;
            width: 400px;
            padding: 10px;
            text-transform: uppercase; /* If you remove this line, the right side link no longer floats outside the container. */
        }
 </style>

</head>

<body>
    <p>
        <a href="#" id="clicked">Clicker</a>
    </p>

    <div class="titlebar">

        <span style="float: left;">Title</span>
        <a href="#" id="rightlink" style="float: right;">Right Side Link</a>

        <br style="clear: both;" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function toggler() {
            var rightlink = document.getElementById("rightlink");
            if (rightlink.innerHTML == "") {
                rightlink.innerHTML = "Right Side Link";
                }
            else {
                rightlink.innerHTML = "";
            }
        }

        document.getElementById("clicked").addEventListener("click", toggler, false);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually adding the words as "RIGHT SIDE LINK" instead of capitalized? It could be the case that the font you are rendering (in Webkit) makes your uppercase letters take up more space, and breaks the boundary for the container. You may need to set a character limit on the link or create add `display:block` to your CSS for the anchor tag.

Comment: Well, minor detail, but the "capitalized" value refers to sentence case.  But even if I set "uppercase" or "lowercase", it doesn't make a difference.  There's most likely enough room because this behaves just fine in other browsers like Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Sure does look like a bug. I searched webkit's bugzilla and I didn't find a report for this, so you may want to report it. http://webkit.org/quality/reporting.html

Based on scott's answer: you can work around it by putting a blank tag in there instead of making it empty.

```
function toggler() {
    var rightlink = document.getElementById("rightlink");
  if (rightlink.innerHTML == "<b></b>") {
        rightlink.innerHTML = "Right Side Link";
        }
    else {
      rightlink.innerHTML = "<b></b>";
    }
}
```